# how to know pexpect command actually ran?

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a command  @ "tool --server=commander.company.com login username" which prompts for "Password". I'm using pexpect to run the command and expecting it and using sendline to 
send the password. There is no error when I run it, but these commands don't seem to run. How can I  know that this actually ran?

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('tool --server=commander.company.com login username')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('#password')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`child.isalive()` and `child.status` are useful to determine the command's execution status, however, [pexpect.spawn](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn) can also be passed an open file to which input and output will be logged. You can then see whether the spawned process is executing as you expect, e.g.

```
import sys
child = pexpect.spawn('tool --server=commander.company.com login username', logfile=sys.stdout)
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('#password')
```

This will send all input and output to your standard output stream. `logfile_read` and `logfile_send` might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible things you can check here:

- `p.isalive()`

> isalive(self) method of pexpect.spawn instance
>       This tests if the child process is running or not. This is
>       non-blocking. If the child was terminated then this will read the
>       exitstatus or signalstatus of the child. This returns True if the child
>       process appears to be running or False if not. It can take literally
>       SECONDS for Solaris to return the right status.

- `p.status`

**Example:**

```
>>> from pexpect import spawn
>>> p = spawn("ls")
>>> p.isalive()
False
>>> p.status
0
```

For more details see: [pexpect Documetnation](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)